# GraphQL query error causes the app to crash

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

```
query getSelectedVersion($id: ID) {
  digitalstandard(id: $id) {
    id
    name
    type
    overview
    disclaimer
    description
  }
}
```

[image]

```
apollo: {
    digitalstandard: {
      query: getSelectedVersion,
      variables() {
        return {
          id: this.$route.query.versionId,
        }
      },
      // Initialize Data
      result({ data }) {
        console.log(data.digitalstandard.data)
      },
      error({ error }) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('error', error)
      },
      // Prevent Query when variable is Null
      skip() {
        return !this.$route.query.versionId
      },
    },
  },
```

The error makes sense. There is no ID so graphQL cannot console.log data of undefined. But it shouldn't crash my app.

The skip method prevents it from running which is a work around but why is the failed graphQL call causing the nuxt server to crash?

Comment: In which step, your app crash exactly ? building or page accessing ?

Comment: Page access. The server was already running with npm run dev and when the page is refreshed, the graphQL query fails, gives me that error and it kills my server automatically.

Comment: @pancake please include `nav-filter-bar.js` component mentioned in error

Comment: So the first time it's ok ?

Comment: If theres no ID in the params it will fail immediately even the first time because theres no ID. the problem is the graphQL error causes server to crash